# How to filter deep array?

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$test = [
    ['teams' => ['home' => 'Lazio']],
    ['teams' => ['away' => 'Inter']]
];
```

I need to search `Inter`, so I did:

```
$key = array_search('Inter', array_column($test, 'teams'));
var_dump($test[$key]);
```

but it returns `false` as `$key`.

Comment: A simple foreach loop? Are you looking for a solution with wrappers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search()` doesn't search nested arrays. There's no built-in functionthat does this, so just use a loop.

```
$key == null;
foreach (array_column($test, 'teams') as $i => $teams) {
    if (in_array('Inter', $teams)) {
        $key = $i;
        break;
    }
}
if ($key !== null) {
    var_dump($test[$key]);
}
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You have enough rep to edit obvious typos like the ones you've been catching me in.

Comment: I never know if someone gets annoyed or not if I do that (it has happened) so I tend to point them out instead :-) But yes, fair comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm bored.  You can filter out non-matching items and then get the key.
You can search for it anywhere in the array without specifying `home`, `away` or other:

```
$key = key(array_filter($test, function($v) { return in_array('Inter', $v['teams']); }));
```

Not the preferred way, but if there is only `home` and `away` you can search using an array:

```
($key = array_search(['away' => 'Inter'], array_column($test, 'teams'))) || 
($key = array_search(['home' => 'Inter'], array_column($test, 'teams')));
```

Or with one `array_column` call:

```
($t = array_column($test, 'teams')) && ($key = array_search(['away' => 'Inter'], $t)) || 
                                       ($key = array_search(['home' => 'Inter'], $t));
```

All of the code above returns the key of the first match.

Answer (score 1):

```
$needle = array_flip(['Inter']);
$result = array_filter(array_column($test, 'teams'), function(array $item) use ($needle) {
    return array_intersect_key(array_flip($item), $needle);
});
```

using $needle as an array (and as result array_intersect_key) just in case you need to find more than one value.

You can change array_intersect_key to isset and single $needle value (instead of array).

also, is better to avoid using the array_search, (also in_array) functions for big arrays because of their complexity of algorithm (eq low performance)